# Center a WPF ListView Column in "code behind"

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, gridview, code-behind

I am trying to center a column in a `ListView` in the code-behind. Since the columns are dynamically created during runtime, there is no option to do this in the XAML.

Here the helper I created. Setting the other properties like font color works fine - any ideas?

```
private void ListViewHelper(GridView gridView, ListView listView, MatrixId assignment, string key, IValueConverter converter)
{
   // new column
   GridViewColumn gridViewColumn = new GridViewColumn();

   // header text and formating
   gridViewColumn.Header = new TextBlock { Text = assignment.Id.ToString(), TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, Padding = new Thickness(7, 0, 0, 0), Width = 50 };

   // databinding & converter
   FrameworkElementFactory frameworkElementFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
   DataTemplate dataTemplate = new DataTemplate();
   dataTemplate.VisualTree = frameworkElementFactory;
   gridViewColumn.CellTemplate = dataTemplate;
   Binding binding = new Binding(assignment.Id.ToString() + key);
   binding.Converter = converter;

   // *** this does not work ***             
   frameworkElementFactory.SetValue(TextBlock.TextAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Right);
   frameworkElementFactory.SetValue(TextBlock.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Right);

   frameworkElementFactory.SetValue(TextBlock.ForegroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(100, 100, 100)));
   frameworkElementFactory.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);

   // add column
   gridView.Columns.Add(gridViewColumn);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center the content in a `GridView` inside a `ListView`, you can do it by creating an item container style for `ListViewItem` and set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` to `Center`.

```
var itemContainerStyle = new Style(typeof(ListViewItem));
var horizontalContentAlignmentSetter = new Setter(HorizontalContentAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
itemContainerStyle.Setters.Add(horizontalContentAlignmentSetter);

listView.ItemContainerStyle = itemContainerStyle;
```

Here, `listView` is your list view instance. The alignment will apply to all columns. If you need to align columns individually, set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` in the item container template to `Stretch`.

```
var itemContainerStyle = new Style(typeof(ListViewItem));
var horizontalContentAlignmentSetter = new Setter(HorizontalContentAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Stretch);
itemContainerStyle.Setters.Add(horizontalContentAlignmentSetter);

listView.ItemContainerStyle = itemContainerStyle;
```

Then set the `HorizontalAlignment` of the controls inside the `CellTemplate` to what you need.

```
private void ListViewHelper(GridView gridView, ListView listView, MatrixId assignment, string key, IValueConverter converter)
{
   // ...your code.

   // Set the alignment to "Left", "Center", "Right" or "Stretch"
   frameworkElementFactory.SetValue(TextBlock.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Right);

   // ...your code.
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. Indeed I check the first option earlier but it centers all colums as you mention. How do set the "item container template" to strech in the code? I just found samples in XAML...

Comment: @Norbert I have added code for individual column alignments.